# How can an angular module use another module and instantiate it with custom value?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-module, angular-providers

I need to have a module that does instantiate another one with a custom variable like the following.

```js
// app.module.ts
MyServiceModule.forRoot({
 custom: 'customVar'
})
```

Then within the `myServiceModule` I try to do the following

```js
#NgModule({
  imports: [
    anotherServiceModule.forRoot({
      custom: // <-- The 'customVar' from MyServiceModule
    }) 
  ]
})
export class MyServiceModule {
  static forRoot(config: {custom: string}) {
    return {
      ngModule: MyServiceModule,
      providers: [
        {
           provide: MyServiceProvider,
           useValue: config,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can I somehow use the instance of my `MyServiceProvider`?

**Edit**
Also, I'm not the owner of `anotherServiceModule`

#### Objectif

I did build an extended language service because the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) was missing some feature that my specific project did required.

I would like to initiate this library with prefix given in the `forRoot()`

Real life example

```js
MyServiceModule.forRoot({
 custom: ['/assets/i18n']
})
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [
          HttpClient, 
          custom //  <-- The 'customVar' from MyServiceModule
        ],
      },
    }),
  ]
}),
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The services within `AnotherServiceModule` could require `MyServiceProvider` as a dependency. I'm guessing that by setting it's `useValue` in `MyServiceModule.forRoot` it would then be available as that value in the other services

I'm assuming `AnotherServiceModule` is something you have control over, and isn't a 3rd party module

If `AnotherServiceModule` is 3rd party, then import it in the `AppModule` - you already know what the custom variable is going to be, so apply it using `AnotherServiceModule.forRoot(...)`

Comment: Hi & thx for your answer. I'm sadly not the owner of `AnotherServiceModule` I did update my question with more detailed information